# Have query show "0" when there are no results in a COUNT with dates

Tags: mysql, count

How do have this calculate and display "0" if there is no count for that week instead of skipping it? E.G --
**Current display:**

```
June 30 2020 |   2020/26 |   2020  |  26 5<br>
August 01 2020  |  2020/30  |  2020 |   30  |  2
```

**Desired Display:**

```
June 30 2020        |      2020/26 2020 26       |      5<br>
July 6th 2020       |      2020/27 2020 27       |      0<br>
July 13 2020       |      2020/28 2020 28       |      0<br>
July 20 2020 v      |      2020/29 2020 29       |      2<br>
```

**my query**

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(booking_date, "%M %d %Y") AS week_Ending, CONCAT(YEAR(booking_date), '/', WEEK(booking_date)) AS week_name,

       YEAR(booking_date), WEEK(booking_date), COUNT(*)

FROM table
GROUP BY CONCAT(YEAR(booking_date), '/', WEEK(booking_date))
ORDER BY YEAR(booking_date) ASC, WEEK(booking_date) ASC
```

The code I have below generates this result:

```
Week_Ending    | Week_Name | YEAR(booking_date) | WEEK(booking_date) | COUNT(*)
---------------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------
June 02 2020   | 2020/22   |               2020 |                 22 |       1
June 16 2020   | 2020/24   |               2020 |                 24 |       1
June 21 2020   | 2020/25   |               2020 |                 25 |       2
June 30 2020   | 2020/26   |               2020 |                 26 |       5
August 01 2020 | 2020/30   |               2020 |                 30 |       2
August 04 2020 | 2020/31   |               2020 |                 31 |       1
August 10 2020 | 2020/32   |               2020 |                 32 |      12
August 16 2020 | 2020/33   |               2020 |                 33 |       4
```

Comment: please provide als the data, where the resuklt come from see [mre]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You would typically use a calendar table, and bring your table with a `left join`. If you don't have a calendar table at hand, you can create one on the fly with a recursive cte (available in MySQL 8.0):

```
with recursive cte as (
    select 
        min(booking_date) - interval weekday(booking_date) day dt,
        max(booking_date) - interval weekday(booking_date) day end_dt
    from mytable
    union all
    select dt + interval 7 day
    from cte
    where dt <= end_dt
)
select 
    c.dt start_of_week, 
    yearweek(c.dt) year_week, 
    year(c.dt) yr,
    week(c.dt) wk,
    count(t.booking_date) cnt
from cte c
left join mytable t 
    on  t.booking_date >= c.dt
    and t.booking_date <  c.dt + interval 7 day
group by c.dt
```

Comment: thank you for this. IF the server isnt running MYSQL 8 can the CTE examples still be used? My understanding is not (obviously not your problem, that is mine)

Answer (score 0):

You created The GROUP BY variable by concatenating data that exists. If data doesn't exist, there's no way for it to know that data **should** exist without some sort of master list.

One way to accomplish this would he o create another table that has all the possible weeks where data **could** exist and incorporate that in your query.